# Десериализация json с помощью gson

Tags: gson, json, java

Когда требуется десериализовать класс с множеством параметров при помощи своего десериализатора, то приходится заниматься штампованием кучи строк текста:

```
class Foo() {
    String param1;
    String param2;
    ...
    String param20;
    ArrayList<String> arrList;
    HashMap<Integer, String> hMap;
}
class FooDeserializator implements JsonDeserializer<Foo>(){
    public Foo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
  throws JsonParseException {
        f= new Foo();
        f.param1=json.getAsJsonObject().get("param1").getAsString();
... // куча строк по количеству параметров
f.param100500=json.getAsJsonObject().get("param100500").getAsString();
...
return f;
}
```

Можно ли написать десериализатор только для вложенных структур вроде `ArrayList`, `HashMap`?

Можно ли десериализовать базовые типы, не переписывая их руками?

Может быть, я вообще всё не так понял, но почему-то класс с вложенными структурами у меня не десериализуется: при попытке обратиться к любому параметру класса возникает ошибка "`cannot cast JsonBalancedTree to Foo`". Может быть это решается другим путем, а не своим десериализатором?

**добавлено**

Минимально демонстрирующий пример из-за чего приходиться делать свой десериализатор:

```
package ru.reinraus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test12 {
    String param1="pampam1";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Test12> arr=new ArrayList<Test12>();
        arr.add(new Test12());
        Test12 t12=new Test12();
        t12.param1="world1";
        arr.add(t12);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonArr=gson.toJson(arr); 
        System.out.println(jsonArr); // [{"param1":"pampam1"},{"param1":"world1"}]
        ArrayList<Test12> arr2= gson.fromJson(jsonArr, arr.getClass());
        String s = arr2.get(1).param1; // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to ru.reinraus.Test12 at ru.reinraus.Test12.main(Test12.java:18)
    }
}
```

Это пример. В реальности же класс с кучей параметров и аррэйлист с экземплярами другого класса. Сериализация проходит нормально, а обращение к результату десериализации приводит к исключению.

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста опечатку в тэге и в заголовке: вместо gson должно быть JSON.

Comment: Нет, не должно быть. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А зачем вы вообще вручную десериализуете ваш класс? В документации по gson есть ответы на оба ваших вопроса:

- [Базовые типы](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples)
- [Коллекции](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types)

Замените десериализацию следующей строкой:

```
ArrayList<Test12> arr2= gson.fromJson(jsonArr, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Test12>>(){}.getType());
```

Для более сложных структур, можно зарегистрировать собственные адаптеры для своих типов. Для коллекций можно зарегистрировать общий адаптер, который будет определять тип хранимых элементов и выполнять необходимую работу.

Comment: @a_gura, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @ReinRaus ничего не изменилось, ответ все еще находится в документации по приведенным ссылкам. Тем не менее, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Повторное чтение документации действительно помогло.